# jqGrid - Trigger reloadGrid inside afterSaveCell method

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to reload my grid after modifying a cell but I get this error message: "Error in ajax request".

Here's my function:

```
afterSaveCell: function(rowid, name, val, iRow, iCol){  
    //... do some stuff ...  
    //save cell in the database  
    //... some more stuff ...  
    $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid")  
}
```

This grid is built on the server (I know my columns only at runtime), so I'm thinking that I should fire the hole `$.ajax()` function (in which all the grid definition is). Is this right? How can I do it?

Comment: Can you use firebug or chrome dev tools to monitor xhr requests?  1) Does a request get fired when you save the grid?  2) If so, can you copy and paste the request in a browser tab (non-ajax) and get a valid result?

Comment: @Jody 1) yes 2) Yes, if by a valid result you mean to see the hole page. I'm using a .net webmethod, the url is Page.aspx/get_json_data?id=someId

Comment: If you are seeing the entire page, could it be that jqgrid is expecting a json string instead?  I suppose your Page.aspx could be determining to only send back a json response if the request is XHR, but from the name of the script I would think not.

Comment: @Jody I see where you're going but the grid is working when I update a cell (I see the updated value in the grid and the database). The problem only occurs when I try to trigger the reloadGrid function inside the afterSaveCell function. Perhaps this its not a place to trigger the reload. I need a full reload to get some columns with calculated values from the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way of doing this. So I did the ajax request (which saves the values in the database) inside the `afterSubmitCell` event and then calculate the rest of the fields inside `afterSaveCell` (using javascript and a lot of `getCell` and `setCell` calls).

In fact this ended up being a better way of doing this since the user doesn't have to wait more than 1 second to see the updated values. Also the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) of the `afterSaveCell` event says:

> Applies only to a cell that is editable; this event fires after the cell has been successfully saved. **This is the ideal place to change other content.**

The downside of going this way is that I have duplicated logic to calculate some columns of the grid (server-side in C# and client-side in javascript)